# Can a check be indorsed anywhere, or just in the specified area?

Tags: united-states, banking, check

So I wanted to know, but nobody has been able to answer me. Can an indorsement be made anywhere on a check, or does it always have to be made in the designated space on the back of the check?

Comment: What I learned on the Internet today: Indorsement.  I have been saying that wrong my entire life. http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/indorsement

Comment: The link indicates that both endorsement and indorsement are correct (`The term indorsement is also spelled endorsement`), so no need to change your lexicon just yet.

Answer (score 4):

It is *required* for the *banks* to put their indorsements in the area in the middle of the back of the check deposited to their accounts:

[Regulation CC (12 CFR 229), Appendix D](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=1b0dd37495302685319396ab4c44b688&node=12:3.0.1.1.10.4.8.11.45&rgn=div9):

> (iii) The indorsement, if applied to an existing paper check, shall be
>   placed on the back of the check so that the routing number is wholly
>   contained in the area 3.0 inches from the leading edge of the check to
>   1.5 inches from the trailing edge of the check.<sup>31</sup>
>
> <sup>31</sup>The leading edge is definded as the right side of the check looking
>   at it from the front. The trailing edge is defined as the left side of
>   the check looking at it from the front. See American National
>   Standards Specifications for the Placement and Location of MICR
>   Printing, X9.13.

So your signature should *not* be in the same area, in order to make the bank stamps readable. Your signature should be in the 3.0 inches space from the leading edge of the check. That is also where the additional indorsements are to be put by other banks handling the check (not the depository bank).

Comment: So it is required that the endorsement be put back on the check?

Comment: Yes, because the check says "Pay to **the order** of". You need to give an order, i.e.: endorse ("for deposit only", for example, or just a signature when you give it to the cashier).

Comment: Ok that makes much more sense now, thanks a bunch.

Comment: Wait what I meant to ask was, it is required that the endorsement is to be made on the back of the check right?

Comment: Are you asking whether you can endorse the check on the front? No, you cannot. Only the person giving you the check can write there.